# How to let the user choose their main/start Activity?

Tags: android

In my App I have three Activities for example: AActivity, BActivity, CActivity.

I want the user to choose their main Activity the Activity should open after he clicks on a Button on Main Screen.

Sorry im new to Android Development.

EDIT: Sorry i forgot to say: i want that the chosen ativity is the new basic Activity (He choose BActivity -> any app start BActivity starts as first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could always use the same activity but load a different fragment based on the users preferences.

Alternatively, use a "launcher" activity that reads the preferences, launches the relevant activity and then closes.

Comment: can you give me a little example what you mean with preferences please? i dont understand what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

You can save which Activity they selected in SharedPreferences and the next time the app loads, check the SharedPreferences and if a default activity has been selected then start that Activity, otherwise give them the option for which activity to set as their start activity.

Comment: thaks, can you make an example how to do that with the SharedPreferences and how to read that please.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger an intent after he clicks on a certain button.

ex. if he click on button 1 activity AActivity opens

```
        Button A = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bA1);
//we get the button from the xml
//then we assign a setOnClickListener to do an 
//action after he clicks on it      
        A.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Intent i = new Intent(Home.this, AActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
//then here we do the action we want which is opening an activity
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is a widget, which will change its state depending on selected option (or other stuff).

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Answer (score -1):

Something like this would work?

```
public class main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            switch(choice){
            case choice1:
                class1.main1();
                break;
            case choice2:
                class2.main2();
                break;
            case choice3:
                class3.main3();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: did you ever develop something with android?